# how to communicatie rocketmq and rocketmq directly?

Tags: rocketmq

I have two network envionments (such as `NETWORK -A` and `NETWORK -B`). Now, I deployed rocketmq-a in the `NETWORK-A`  and  deployed rocketmq-b in the `NETWORK-B`, how to communicate  rocketmq-a and rocketmq-b directly? 
[image]

Comment: What do you mean communicate? Do you mean rocektmq-b is a slave of rocketmq-a?

Comment: The communicate mean that rocketmq-a can send messages to rocketmq-b. Rocketmq-b is not a salve of rocketmq-a. For example: rocketmq-a in a network environment in New York，rocketmq-b in a network environment in London.Does rocketmq-a send messages to rocketmq-b?

Comment: The broker itself can not send messages. What I understand is that, you have a service A in New York subscribed topic from rocketmq-a,which is also in New York. And  service A needs to send messages to the rocketmq-broker in London, is that so?

Comment: Service A needs send messages to the rocketmq-a，which is in New York. And rocketmq-a needs to send messages to the rocketmq-b,which is in London. (Service A----->rocketmq-a------>rocketmq-b----->Service b)

Comment: What do you mean rocketmq-a needs to send message? Broker can not send messages, only client can send message, do you mean you want to replicate the message to rocketmq-b?

Comment: yes,Rocketmq-a needs to send message. I want to replicate the message to rocketmq-b. Please，can i  replicate the message to rocketmq-b? you said: " only client can send message" , do you mean rocketmq-a' client  send message to rocketmq-b?

Comment: please check my answers

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you have two rocketmq clusters and one message should replicate to another rocketmq cluster.

So this is a message replication.

you have two choices:

1. Implement a send message hook
2. Use a messageStore plugIn that extend `AbstractPluginMessageStore` and load it using broker configuration

Both of them needs to implement replication by yourself.

---

However, if you make them the same broker group, it is very easy.

Just make rocketmq-b as a slave of rocketmq-a, and deploy them in different machine room.

Then rocketmq-b will only provide read operations and always replicate the data from master